# Choice of version control, ticketing and planning platforms - July 2011

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking, project-planning, ticket-system

Rarely in an organization's lifetime is it easy to choose development platforms.  Now is the time for my startup - we have to commit to a version control platform / service and set up some form of ticketing and project planning.

Every year brings new developments in these fields so I feel justified in asking what may well be a FAQ.  My question is specific to:

- Now (mid 2011)
- A small software startup (1-2 developers) but likely to grow
- Very low cost (especially to start with)

The latest trends seem to be distributed version control with git and mercurial front runners.  And in 2011, it seems no-one hosts their own version control - just pay monthly for the service.  Amalgamation of issue tracking and planning/estimation is another current theme, with this also hosted in the cloud.

Right now I am thinking of a paid, private **github** repo for source control - this would make it easier to bring open source developers into the team.  And **FogBugz** for issue tracking/planning - I'm impressed by the UI and evidence-based milestone estimation.

So my question in a nutshell: what are the forerunners for version control and planning in 2011?  What are the themes that are shaping this space?

Comment: A very quick search here in StackOverflow gives recommendations for all of these.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the ones that you think might work, try them out (most options have a "trial" if they are not free services), and then go with what works for your team. The best way to figure out what works is to try it.

My recommendation is to start with the simplest things you can and only add additional tools if you need them (try them out, sure, but don't require their use). The overhead of most tools is very large for small teams just starting out. Focus on your business value-added items. Time and effort spent working with / configuring various tools is time you are not building things your customers want.

That said, use whatever tools you are used to using right now, and build out from there. Go with the strengths of your team first, and then look to remove pain points as you go.